# Distribute equally spaced point along a line starting from the beginning of the line

Tags: qgis, line, distance

I have a line geometry shapefile and I'd like to add a point each 111.12 km traveled alongside this line starting from the beginning of the line.

I've tried with the "Points along geometry" function in QGIS setting the beginning and ending offsets to 0, but it does not work. The first point is only roughly 50 km from the beginning of my line and there are multiple parts on the line were two adjacent points are less than 111.12 km away (way less, like 20 km). I've marked these errors on the attached image. A similar thing happens with the analogous function in ArcGIS.  [image: point distribution error]

What could be the problem and how could that be solved? Solution does not have to be in QGIS/ArcGIS mandatorily, I also have available Matlab, R and Python

Comment: We are looking at two lines? Try Dissolving them first to create one line

Comment: A lot of things could be responsible for this - several lines (as mentioned by @BERA), CRS issue etc. Without more details: difficult to say. Sharing your data could help.